# MahApps style should not apply to all items

Tags: wpf, xaml, mahapps.metro

I noticed when adding the MahApps.Metro styles to my resource dictionary that these styles are being applied to all items within my application, this is not the desired effect. I only want to use the ToggleSwitch and Combobox Styles. How can this be achieved?

Thanx!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

put only the following resource dictionaries in your xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary>
  <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colours.xaml" />
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.Buttons.xaml" />
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.ComboBox.xaml" />
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Blue.xaml" />
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml" />
  </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

  <Style TargetType="ToggleButton" BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroToggleButton}" />
  <Style TargetType="ComboBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroComboBox}" />
  <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroComboBoxItem}" />
</ResourceDictionary>
```

hope this helps

Comment: Thanx this helped!! Only problem now it that the ToggleSwitches are only gray. Any suggestions?

Comment: @ChrisjanL i forgot the accents colors, this must help

Comment: Hi I was wondering if there was a way to change the colour of the title bar when working with mahapps? Its light blue currently but lets say I want it orange?

Comment: @ChrisjanLodewyks hi, you can use one of the 5 different accents: Blue, Green, Orange, Purple, Red (with BaseDark or BaseLight). note that this changes the complete ui theme.